# How can I get my currentState in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to push my List data to the database through my model and I want to get my currentState.

```
class SettingsDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChexiUser user;

  SettingsDialog({this.user});
  @override
  _SettingsDialogState createState() => _SettingsDialogState();
}
```

Here is my Stateful Widget that creates a mutable widget _SettingsDialogState. I have a class called Options that has a static List function getOptions(user) to map my options on a DataTable.

```
class Option {
  String name;
  String option;
  String description;
  bool value;
  Object user;
  String valueString;

  Option(
    {this.name,
     this.option,
     this.description,
     this.user,
     this.value,
     this.valueString});

 static List<Option> getOptions(user) {
   return <Option>[
   Option(
      name: 'autoPass',
      value: user.settingsAutoPass,
      option: 'Auto Pass',
      description:
          'The game will automatically roll the dice when a new turn starts or a double is rolled'),
   Option(
      name: 'autoRoll ',
      value: user.settingsAutoRoll,
      option: 'Auto Roll',
      description:
          'The game will automatically pass the dice if there is no move'),
    Option(
      name: 'showCheckMoves ',
      value: user.settingsShowCheckMoves,
      option: 'Show Check Move',
      description:
          'When an opponent can be put in check, highlight the squares (from, to) that will lead to a 
      check '),
    Option(
      name: 'showFileRank ',
      value: user.settingsShowFileRank,
      option: 'Show File Rank',
      description:
          'Show the files and ranks on the sides of the gameboard'),
  Option(
      name: 'showLastOpponentMove',
      value: user.settingsShowLastOpponentMove,
      option: 'Show Last Opponent Move',
      description:
          ' The opponent\'s last move (from, to) will show as a different colored square'),
    Option(
      name: 'showMateMoves',
      value: user.settingsShowMateMoves,
      option: 'Show Mate Move',
      description:
          'When an opponent can be put in mate, highlight the squares (from,to) that will lead to a 
      mate'),];
  }
}
```

In my _SettingsDialogState class widget I have initialize the options

```
class _SettingsDialogState extends State<SettingsDialog> {
  List<Option> options;

@override
void initState() {
  options = Option.getOptions(widget.user);
  super.initState();
}
```

Now on my DataTable I have called setState(() {}) everytime there are changes to update the values of my initState and it's working so well. Now I want my data to be saved on a model function and I need the data on the state and I don't know how to get my data. Should I should pass the options list to my save function or just call the currentState of my widget. I'm stuck and I have been searching for solutions online. I tried passing the options list but when I print it out it calls Option instance. I need your expertise on this one. Thanks guys I know I'm close I just need to know how to execute. Or Am I close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid initializing variables statically.

```
  options = Option.getOptions(widget.user);
```

Instead define it as a variable in the widget and assign the values using constructor.

```
class SettingsDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChexiUser user;
  final List<Option> options;


  SettingsDialog({this.user,this.options});
  @override
  _SettingsDialogState createState() => _SettingsDialogState();
}
```

Inside your state class, you can access that value using `widget.options`.

### How can I get my currentState in Flutter?

Always drive the UI using a model class. Keep the model class inside your business logic class. You can use any of the State management techniques to manage these models. Some popular options are flutter_bloc, provider etc.

Read more from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

Comment: Thanks, added your suggestion to the code but my problem is still there. Here is my function 

    saveOptions() {
       print(widget.options);
    }

Result: [Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option', Instance of 'Option']

Comment: The reason it prints 'Instance of Option' is, you forgot to implement toString for the Option class.

Comment: print(widget.options.toString()); Still the same. I want to format it to a body to be passed on to a cloud function. Something like body: {'name': options.name, 'value': option.value});

Comment: you can convert it into json then

Comment: here you can find detailed example about parsing/converting json with model class.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom `toString` method for your `Option` class like this

```
@override
String toString(){
  return '{"name": "$name", "description": "$description"}';
}
```